# How to Pass form value to django view?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible to pass values from custom forms to a function in django view without using models ?

For example in my html I have :

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
<input type="text" name="roll_number">
<button type="submit" class="save   btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Is it possible to pass roll_number to view without creating a model class?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they will be accessible through the request object's `POST` attribute which behaves like a Python `dict`, for example in your case:

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        roll_number = request.POST['roll_number']
        # You can now manipulate the form data.
```

Comment: It didn't work ,  def roll_number(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        roll_number = request.POST['roll_number']
        print(roll_number)

Comment: I'm sorry I was editing the comment , got deleted by mistake

Answer (score 3):

aumo's answer describes how you can access attributes sent via POST, and I should be adding this as a comment to it, but I don't have enough reputation.

I don't see an [action attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) in your form tag. It specifies where to send the form data.

`<form method="post" class="post-form" action="page-url">`

Make sure that `page-url` is a url that corresponds with your various `urls.py` files. If it isn't, your view won't be called at all. Add `print` statements to the the top of your view to see if it is being called. The output will appear in your console.